# How can I make the colors of the command prompt dynamic?

Tags: bash

My attempt to change the colors of the prompt depending on the state of an environment variable:

```
tw_prompt_color () {
if [[ ! -z $TASKRC ]]; then
  echo '\033[34m\'
else
  echo '\033[32m\'
fi
}
export -f tw_prompt_color

PS1="\[$(tw_prompt_color)]iMac5K@ \[\033[33;1m\]\w:\[\033[m\]\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] "
```

This doesn't work. The prompt remains the same color regardless of the state of `$TASKRC` unless I manually run `exec bash`. But oddly, adding `exec bash` into the `tw_prompt_color` function doesn't help.

Comment: What file are you editing? Do you close and reopen the terminal after editing it?

Comment: Because you're defining PS1 with a double-quoted string, the command substitution is called only once, instead of every time. Try changing to single quotes: `PS1='...'`

Comment: That resulted in `\033[32m\]iMac5K@....`

Comment: What I also don't get is I'm doing the same thing as the `$(parse_git_branch)` to display the git branch that I have in there and that is dynamic.

Comment: You escape the `$(...)` command substitution for parse_git_branch, but not for tw_prompt_color: escape that one and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Maybe use this approach as a starting point to create your own solution.

**1. Edit your ~/.bashrc**

```
fancy_git_prompt(){
    git_info=`git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
    if [ "${git_info}" ]; then
        if [ "$(git status -s)" ]; then
            git_color='\033[1;31m'
        else
            git_color='\033[1;36m'
        fi
        echo -e "${git_color}git:${git_info}"
    fi
}

PS1='\n\[\033[1;32m\][\w] $(fancy_git_prompt)\[\033[0m\]\n\$ '
```

**2. Reload ~/.bashrc**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

There are more advanced versions out there, e.g. [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)

Comment: Didn't help. I also have a somehting similar to "fancy_git_prompt" in my bash config. It works. The color change doesn't.

Comment: After **Step 2** it should work. You need that `source ...` command to make the new prompt available in your login session.

Comment: even after starting a new terminal session it doesn't work.

Comment: Besides of `$(parse_git_branch)` which isn´t defined in my environment, your code at least does change my prompt.

Comment: It changes mine too but only after I run `exec bash`.

Comment: How about the versions I´ve provided in my answer? Do they work for you? Maybe use them as starting point to create your own solution.

Comment: I'm getting close. I used `echo -e` in there and did the single quotes as suggeted above. The colors are now changing. Something is a little funky with formatting though.

Comment: Bam! Got it. Bash drives me nuts and I'm a perl guy.

Comment: I think it's funny when people used to complain about perl "line noise", as if they've never had to write shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this works:

```
tw_prompt_color () {
if [[ ! -z $TASKRC ]]; then
  echo -e '\033[34m'
else
  echo -e '\033[32m'
fi
}
export -f tw_prompt_color

PS1='$(tw_prompt_color)iMac5K@ \[\033[33;1m\]\w:\[\033[m\]\[\033[33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] '
```

Fix #1: Change to single quotes as suggested. I still don't understand why this worked when the `$(parse_get_branch)` bit worked fine with double quotes.

Fix #2: Add `-e` to the echo command.

Fix #3: Remove some of the now extraneous brackets and escaping. Totally don't get why I need to do that now but it works.

If anyone who can shed light on my bash cluelessness, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The terminal commands controlling colours are weird. For bash to print the prompt perfectly, non-printing things (the colour codes) need to be enclosed in `\[...\]`

Comment: Interesting reading: [Why is printf better than
echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 0):

Bash parses the `PS1` string in two passes:

1. During the first pass, Bash handles [all of `PS1's` special characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html), including `\a` for a bell, `\t` for the time, and `\[` to introduce non-printing characters like color codes.
2. During the second pass, Bash performs the usual parameter expansion, command substitution, etc...  The second pass is optional based on [the `promptvars` shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).
3. There is no third pass.

This means that any special characters that appear directly in `PS1` are recognized.  Even special characters within command substitutions are recognized and replaced.

```
$ PS1="\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ "
12:14:43 $
12:14:43 $ # The time appears in blue.
12:14:44 $
12:14:44 $ PS1="$ "
$
$
$
$ PS1="\$(echo -nE '\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$') "
12:15:02 $
12:15:02 $
12:15:04 $ PS1="$ "
$
```

On the other hand, if the special characters are introduced later by command substitution, then they are not replaced.  This holds for both functions and scripts.

```
$ declare -f prompt_func
prompt_func ()
{
    echo -nE '\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ '
}
$ PS1="\$(prompt_func) "
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ # Special characters are not replaced, including \t.
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ PS1="$ "
$
$
$
$ cat /usr/bin/prompt_script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -nE '\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ '
$ PS1="\$(prompt_script)"
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$
\[\033[00;94m\]\t\[\033[00m\] \$ PS1="$ "
$
```

This leaves two options for formatting `PS1`:

1. When the formatting can be embedded directly in `PS1`, then Bash's special prompt characters can be used.
2. When the formatting must be applied indirectly, then alternatives to Bash's special prompt characters must be found.

The `echo` command and its `-e` option are good alternatives to using color codes directly in `PS1`.  In this case, [`\x01` and `\x02` are alternatives to `PS1's` `\[` and `\]`](https://superuser.com/questions/301353/escape-non-printing-characters-in-a-function-for-a-bash-prompt) codes for identifying non-printing characters.  (`echo -e` will print, unmodified, any `\[` and `\]` that it encounters.)  Identifying non-printing characters is important:

- Correctly identified non-printing characters are required to calculate the prompt length.
- A correctly calculated prompt length is required for proper formatting in the terminal.

The `date` command can be used instead of `\t`.

```
$ cat /usr/bin/prompt_custom
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -ne "\x01\033[00;94m\x02$(date +%T)\x01\033[00m\x02 \$ "
$ PS1="\$(prompt_custom)"
12:53:15 $
12:53:15 $
12:53:15 $
12:53:16 $ PS1="$ "
$
```